# Is it possible to install Cyanogenmod on a SPH-D710 (Boost Mobile S2)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms

How do you go about doing it? I couldn't find any instructions for installing the latest version of Cyanogenmod on it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

CyanogenMod does not officially support the Epic 4G Touch (SPH-D710) phone. Your best bet would be finding an unofficial port over at [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/epic-4g-touch/development) forums.

From the looks of it, Jelly Bean [4.2.2](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2050948) and [4.3.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2238252) are the latest versions of custom ROMs that are available.  These are not pure CM though. Details and installation instructions at the links.